# Memory partially deallocating in a Linked list

Tags: c

Chatgpt Explanation of the code:

The code defines a double linked list data structure consisting of List and Item structs. The populate() function creates four List structs, each with one or two Item structs, and links them together to form a board. The printboard() function prints out the board by iterating through the linked lists and printing the names of each list and its items. The clearboard() function frees the memory used by the board by iterating through the linked lists and freeing the memory used by each list and its items. The main() function calls populate() to create the board, then calls printboard() to print it, then calls clearboard() to free the memory used by it.

Problem:

not all the data is freed: I checked this by setting printing the board after I 'cleared the board' (freed the data). however my output was:

```
↑+┴
        É#┴
É#┴
        (-┴
É#┴
        É#┴
        Item2
É#┴
        É#┴
        Item2
```

the random ascii makes sense as it is trying to access memory which is not set: however Item2 still shows up.

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

//initialize
typedef struct List {
    char name[30];
    struct Item *firstitem;
    struct List *prevList;
    struct List *nextList;
}List;
typedef struct Item {
    char name[30];
    struct Item *previtem;
    struct Item *nextitem;

}Item;
void populate(List** ); //put data in
void printboard(List* ); //print data
void clearboard(List** ); // clear data
int main(void)
{
    //initalize double linked list:
    List *board = malloc(sizeof(List));
    populate(&board);
    //printf("%s", board);
    printboard(board);
    printf("\n\n");
    clearboard(&board);
    printboard(board);
}

void populate(List** board)
{
    //List 1
    List* List1 = malloc(sizeof(List));
    strcpy(List1->name, "List");

    Item* Item1_1 = malloc(sizeof(Item));
    strcpy(Item1_1->name, "Item1");
    Item* Item1_2 = malloc(sizeof(Item));
    strcpy(Item1_2->name, "Item2");
    
    // List 2
    List* List2 = malloc(sizeof(List));
    strcpy(List2->name, "List");

    Item* Item2_1 = malloc(sizeof(Item));
    strcpy(Item2_1->name, "Item1");
    Item2_1->nextitem = NULL;
    Item* Item2_2 = malloc(sizeof(Item));
    strcpy(Item2_2->name, "Item2");

    
    //list 3
    List* List3 = malloc(sizeof(List));
    strcpy(List3->name, "List");
    //! ask why this is not list1->next = list2

    Item* Item3_1 = malloc(sizeof(Item));
    strcpy(Item3_1->name, "Item1");

    //list 4
    List* List4 = malloc(sizeof(List));
    strcpy(List4->name, "List");
    Item* Item4_1 = malloc(sizeof(Item));
    strcpy(Item4_1->name, "Item1");
    

    //setting up links between the name and two items. name -> item1 -> item2 -> null
    List1->firstitem = Item1_1;
    Item1_1->nextitem = Item1_2;
    Item1_2->nextitem = NULL;

    Item2_2->nextitem = NULL;
    List2->firstitem = Item2_1;
    Item2_1->nextitem = Item2_2;

    List3->firstitem = Item3_1;
    Item3_1->nextitem = NULL;

    Item4_1->nextitem = NULL;
    List4->firstitem = Item4_1;

    List1->nextList = NULL;
    List2->nextList = List1;
    List3->nextList = List2;
    List4->nextList = List3;

    List1->prevList = List2;
    List2->prevList = List3;
    List3->prevList = List4;
    List4->prevList = NULL; //made it like a stack. list1 prints last while list 4 prints first

    *board = List4;
    //PrintBoard(board);
    //return board;
}

void printboard(List* board)
{
    List *current = board;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        Item *currentitem = current->firstitem;
        printf("%s \n", current->name);
        while (currentitem != NULL)
        {
            printf("\t%s\n", currentitem->name);
            currentitem = currentitem->nextitem;
        }
        current = current->nextList;
    }

}

void clearboard(List** board)
{
    List* currentList = *board;
    while (currentList != NULL)
    {
        Item* currentItem = currentList->firstitem;
        while (currentItem != NULL)
        {
            Item* temp = currentItem;
            currentItem = currentItem->nextitem;
            free(temp);
        }
        List* tempList = currentList;
        currentList = currentList->nextList;
        free(tempList);
    }
    //*board = NULL;
}
```

My current output:

```
List 
        Item1
List
        Item1
List
        Item1
        Item2
List
        Item1
        Item2


↑+┴
        É#┴
É#┴
        (-┴
É#┴
        É#┴
        Item2
É#┴
        É#┴
        Item2
```

I was expecting :

```
List 
        Item1
List
        Item1
List
        Item1
        Item2
List
        Item1
        Item2


↑+┴
        É#┴
É#┴
        (-┴
É#┴
        
        É#┴
É#┴
        É#┴
        É#┴
```

Comment: FYI you appear to be leaking memory with `List *board = malloc(sizeof(List));` given that you immediately call `populate(&board)` which overwrites `board`. No need to malloc anything here as `populate()` does it for you.

Comment: Are you saying it's not `free`d because  you still see `"Item2"`?  `free`ing memory doesn't clear the memory nor set your pointer to `NULL`.

Comment: I thought it wasn't free because I saw it yes. Does this mean my code is working fine?

Comment: Basically all `free` is doing is telling the system that the memory is available for use again by `malloc`. It doesn't "clear" any memory, and it *can't* change the pointer variable (to be e.g. `NULL`). So as long as you `free` what is returned by `malloc`, then you're good. Also, accessing any memory allocated by `malloc`, after you have called `free`, leads to *undefined behavior*.